# How do I input values from a file into a matrix?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I would like to enter specific values into the matrix using a function, but I keep receiving the segmentation fault due to some error located in the matInit function.  I receive this error regardless of whether I set it up as bar.col[i].els[k]=0 ( as I did below) or if I save bar.col[i] as an array and do a for loop with the k values.  I feel that the segmentation fault is due to the dimensions not matching up, but I don't see what I am doing wrong.  I also have to enter the values through the strutures as that is a requirement for this project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Vector {
  float* els;  
  int len;
};

struct Matrix {
  Vector* col; 
  int ncols;    // total number of columns in matrix
};

// Initializer functions for our structures
Vector vecInit(int);     // Provided below
Matrix matInit(int,int); // ** You must complete this

// Overloaded operators
Vector operator+(Vector,Vector);  // Provided below
Vector operator*(float,Vector);   // ** You must write this 
Vector operator*(Matrix,Vector);  // ** You must write this
istream& operator>>(istream&, Vector&); // Provided below
istream& operator>>(istream&, Matrix&); // ** You must write this

// Other Vector functions
float vecDot(Vector,Vector); // ** You must write this

//    main code 
// **** This must be left unchanged in your submission *****
int main(void) {
  int m,n,nv,nw;
  ifstream fin("mat.def");

  if (!fin.is_open()) {
    cout << "Cannot find file mat.def!" << endl;
  }
  else {
   // Load details of matrix M from file
    fin >> m >> n;
    Matrix M = matInit(m,n);
fin >> M;
cout << "M is " << m << "x" << n << endl;



  }

  return 0;

}
// *****************************************************

//    Support function definitions 

// ** Provided Code.  Do not change **

// Vector structure initializer

// *** Partially provided code.  Change as needed below ***

//     Matrix structure initializer
    Matrix matInit(int m, int n) {
  Matrix bar;

bar.ncols = n;
bar.col = new Vector[m];  



for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {

for (int k=0;k<m;k++) {
bar.col[i].els[k]=0;
}
}







  return bar;

}


istream& operator>>(istream& input, Matrix& M) {
int leng=M.col[0].len;


for (int i=0;i<M.ncols;i++) {
for (int k=0;k<leng;k++) {

input >> M.col[i].els[k];
}
}
  return input;
}
```

Comment: The shown code is mostly unreadable due to random, haphazard indentation. Please clean up your code, and indent it correctly, so that it's readable and legible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We ask for [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com), and not just for our own convenience. If you had pared this down to a minimal case, you might have discovered the problem on your own.

Comment: My apologies, I'll keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must allocate arrays in each vectors before assigning values to their elements.

```
Matrix matInit(int m, int n) {
  Matrix bar;

  bar.ncols = n;
  bar.col = new Vector[n]; // use n instead m for consistency

  for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    bar.col[i].els = new float[m]; // add this line to allocate arrays
    for (int k=0;k<m;k++) {
      bar.col[i].els[k]=0;
    }
  }

  return bar;
}
```